# Idiom for bringing up a topic in text prematurely

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm writing a thesis, and have to bring up a concept which is part of the topic in the following section. I suppose I am looking for an idiomatic way to "excuse" this break of flow.

In Norwegian there is a phrase/idiom for bringing up a topic earlier than what would seem natural: "foregripe begivenheten". Directly translated it is "anticipate the event", but this does not seem fitting.

Edit: Many great answers below. I simply accepted the one I ended up using. This is not to say that any of the other answers are less good. I wouldn't know.

Comment: Something like a [flash-forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashforward)? Perhaps an example would help clarify what you're asking for.

Comment: 'Give a sneak preview' works in informal registers.  'If I might anticipate myself, ...' could be used in a lecture.

Comment: If the reader will interpret it as a break in flow, then it clearly isn’t necessary.  Change your text so that it ***is*** natural to introduce your topic and then introduce without apology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought "jump the gun" might work here.  However, I think a better choice would be to "get ahead of myself".

From [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_ahead_of_oneself) **get ahead of oneself**

- (idiomatic) To speak or write in a manner in which one makes points out of logical or chronological sequence.
- (idiomatic) To develop an opinion based on insufficient information or to take action prematurely.
- (idiomatic) To focus excessively on one's plans or on prospective future events without paying adequate attention to the present.

So one might say, "I may be **getting ahead of myself** here, but I wish to mention that .... "

Answer (score 1):

*to anticipate (the topic)*

> 2.1 Come or take place before (an event or process expected or scheduled for a later time)
>   ‘this is to anticipate the argument’

([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anticipate))

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to give a hint of what might follow:

> [**foreshadow** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/foreshadow)
>
> Be a warning or indication of (a future event)
>
> *‘other new measures are foreshadowed in the White Paper’*
>
> *‘It establishes a mood and foreshadows future events.’*

'Foreshadow' is a bit more common to my ear when used as a device in fiction or film yet the examples in the dictionary above use it more broadly.